# Order the list based on order of another list

Tags: java, list, dictionary, arraylist

I have two lists where the order of one list is different from the order of other list, in the list I am adding a map where key order is different in both lists. I want the order of both the list same.  How can I perform this?

```
Map<Long, String> attfieldMap = null;
attfieldMap = view.getNameMap(form);

List<Field> auditMap = new ArrayList<Field>();
if (itemId != 0) {

    Item dom = getRecord();

    Map<FormField, Object> tempValues = dom.getValues();
    List<Field> oldValues = new ArrayList<Field>();

    for (Map.Entry<FormField, Object> values : tempValues
            .entrySet()) {
        Field oldFld = new Field();
        Form form = (Form) values.getKey();

        if (attfieldMap.get(form.getField().getId()) != null) {
            oldFld.setKey(attfieldMap.get(form.getField()
                    .getId()));
            oldFld.setValue(values.getValue());

            oldValues.add(oldFld);
        }
    }
}


for (Map.Entry<Long, String> attfieldEntry : attfieldMap.entrySet()) {
    // Mandates to declare within loop
    Field attributeFld = new Field;

    attributeFld.setKey(attfieldEntry.getValue());
    attributeFld.setValue(String.valueOf(attfieldEntry.getKey()));

    auditMap.add(attributeFld);
}
```

The list `auditMap` has map with key `att13`, `att12`, `att14` and `oldValues` has map with key `att12`, `att13`, `att14`. I need this list to be in same order as `auditMap` list.  How to order this?

As per the answeres the below code edited :Here the data gets copied,iwant just the sort,even though the list size is different.list1 should have its own data,list2 should have same data,but the order should be maintained

```
List<Field> auditMap = new ArrayList<Field>();
            attfieldMap = View
                    .getFieldID(form);

            for (Map.Entry<Long, String> attfieldEntry : attfieldMap.entrySet()) {

                Field attributeFld = new Field();

                attributeFld.setKey(attfieldEntry.getValue());
                attributeFld.setValue(String.valueOf(attfieldEntry.getKey()));

                auditMap.add(attributeFld);
                attributeFld = null;
            }

            if (itemId != 0) {

                Item dom = getRecord(domainItem);

                Map<FormField, Object> tempValues = dom.getValues();
                List<Field> oldValues = new ArrayList<Field>();

                for (Map.Entry<FormField, Object> values : tempValues
                        .entrySet()) {
                    Field oldFld = new Field();
                    Form form = (Form) values.getKey();

                    if (attfieldMap.get(form.getField().getId()) != null) {
                        oldFld.setKey(attfieldMap.get(form.getField()
                                .getId()));
                        oldFld.setValue(values.getValue());

                        oldValues.add(oldFld);
                    }

                }
                final Map<Field, Integer> indices = new HashMap<Field, Integer>();
                for (int i = 0; i < oldValues.size(); i++) {
                    indices.put(oldValues.get(i), i);
                }
                Collections.sort(auditMap, new Comparator<Field>() {
                    public int compare(Field o1, Field o2) {
                        int index1 = indices.containsKey(o1) ? indices.get(o1)
                                : -1;
                        int index2 = indices.containsKey(o2) ? indices.get(o2)
                                : -1;
                        return index1 - index2;
                    }
                });
                for (int i = 0; i < oldValues.size(); i++) {
                    LOGGER.info("the new data is--" + oldValues.get(i).getKey());
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < auditMap.size(); i++) {
                    LOGGER.info("the new data is--" + auditMap.get(i).getKey());
                }
```

This is my actual code,the data is not getting ordered.The keys in auditMap are 1,2,3,4 and in old values are 1,3,2 the result of old values should be 1,2,3 but its not happening

Comment: AFAIU there is no way to guarantee the order of entries in an entry set.  I suspect you are using the entirely wrong data structure(s) to achieve 'same ordering'.

Comment: the data in both the list are coming from other approaches.

Comment: `The list auditMap has map with key att13, att12, att14` do you intend to refer to attfieldmap?

Comment: @tobias_k please look into my edited code again,its still not working

Comment: I can not run your code, because I do not have the whole context, but when I test my algorithm, it works. Currently, my guess would be that the `Fields` do not compare properly. Does `f1.equals(f2)` return `true` for field that should be equal? Have you tried Vikdor's approach, too?

Comment: i wanted this approach only coz the data in both the list will be unequal so i just want to order the existing data

Comment: I know that the lists will be unequal; the question was whether `equals` is implemented correctly for the Fields class. The instances in the `oldValues` and `auditMap` lists are not the *same* instances (both are created by different `new` statements), so `equals` has to be implemented correctly for both Vikdor's and my solution to work. Please create two instances of `Field` that should be equal (e.g. having the same `key` and `value`) and check whether `f1.equals(f2)` return `true`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you want is that, at the end of that code snippet, both auditMap and oldValues should be in same order, just run them through Collections.sort() method with appropriate comparator for the Field objects.

If not, then create auditMapArray, a Field Array of size as that of oldValues (you certainly need to declare this outside `IF` block), after the `IF` block. Everytime you want to insert an element into auditMap, find its index in oldValues (assuming you have proper equals method implementation to check if two `Field` objects are equal) and insert at the same location in auditMapArray too, and finally get the auditMap list using `Arrays.asList(auditMapArray)`.

Modified version of your code snippet that ensures that all the values in oldValues that are present in auditMap are in the same order. Any additional elements into auditMap are appended at the end.

```
Map<Long, String> attfieldMap = null;
attfieldMap = view.getNameMap(form);

List<Field> oldValues = new ArrayList<Field>();
if (itemId != 0) {

    Item dom = getRecord();

    Map<FormField, Object> tempValues = dom.getValues();

    for (Map.Entry<FormField, Object> values : tempValues
            .entrySet()) {
        Field oldFld = new Field();
        Form form = (Form) values.getKey();

        if (attfieldMap.get(form.getField().getId()) != null) {
            oldFld.setKey(attfieldMap.get(form.getField()
                    .getId()));
            oldFld.setValue(values.getValue());

            oldValues.add(oldFld);
        }
    }
}

List<Field> otherFields = new ArrayList<Field>();
Field [] auditMapArray = new Field[oldValue.size()];
int index;
for (Map.Entry<Long, String> attfieldEntry : attfieldMap.entrySet()) {
    // Mandates to declare within loop
    Field attributeFld = new Field;

    attributeFld.setKey(attfieldEntry.getValue());
    attributeFld.setValue(String.valueOf(attfieldEntry.getKey()));

    index = oldValues.indexOf(attributeFld);
    if (index > 0) {
        auditMapArray[index] = attributeFld;
    }
    else
    {
        System.err.println(attributeFld + " not found in oldValues");
        otherFields.add(attributeFld);
    }
}

List<Field> auditMap = Arrays.asList(auditMapArray);
auditMap.addAll(otherFields);
```

Comment: what if the there is no order (the first list elements are random) and just want that the second list order to be the same?

Comment: @Vikdor can you please show me with an example,i am not clear

Comment: @Vikdor i am not getting how to apply the above logic to my snippet ,were i need just the oldValues to be ordered has auditMap list.I am still not clear.

Comment: since auditMap is filled much later than the oldValues list, you need to rebuild your auditMap by reordering its contents as per the order in oldValues, using that string array and for loop.

Comment: @Vikdor Its not working out for me,auditMap can be filled before oldValues list also,I tried your snippet applying to mine but its not getting ordered

Comment: @pars, please check out my latest edit with modified version of your code snippet.

Comment: Yes, provided what you care for is that the elements in both the lists must be in the same order at the end of your code snippet. But from your code, it appears that auditMap might contain more elements than that in oldValues. Is that true? If so, sorting will ensure that the relative ordering of elements is the same in both lists, but the count will not be.

Comment: @Vikdor auditMap might have some extra keys but not oldValues,how can i apply the sort logic in the above snippet?

Comment: That's what I meant in the later part of my earlier response, about relative ordering. The elements in auditMap might be [1, 2, 5, 7] and that in oldValues might be [ 1, 5, 7]. So the ordering of the keys is retained on sorting, using the logic given by tobias_k above.

Comment: @Vikdor list1.indexOf(o1) - list1.indexOf(o2); will return me what data i am not clear with the below sort logic

Comment: @para, oops! forgot to mention to replace that line with o1.compareTo(o2) where o1 and o2 are of type Field and implement the compareTo method in Field class, returning 0 when o1 and o2 are equal and non-zero otherwise.

Comment: @Vikdor it would be great if you edit the below code and reply so that it wil be helpfull for others.Please apply to my snippet only

Comment: I modified my code (whose base is your snippet) to make sure the oldValues' elements in auditMap are in the same order. The additional elements in auditMap are pushed towards the end.

Comment: @Vikdor i have tried out its working for the sample,I'l try out in office and post here,thanks

Comment: @Vikdor i have query regarding below sort function,if the auditMap and olsdValues has unequal data then how the sorting will work.

Comment: @pars, The elements that are present in oldValues and in auditMap will be of same order. Any new elements in auditMap will be towards the end.

Comment: @Vikdor Idont want the data from auditMap to be copied to oldValues,i just need sort,even if the size is not equal

Comment: No, it doesn't copy data between oldValues and auditMap. it just orders the elements in both the lists in the same order.

Comment: @Vikdor please check my above code edited in the post,main class

Comment: I share the same concerns as tobias_k raised in the comment above. Not sure what you intend to do with inserting the map as is in lists?

Comment: @Vikdor please look into my edited code its still not working :(

Answer (score 3):

You could sort the second list using a custom comparator, using the items' indices in the first list as key. Something like this:

```
Collections.sort(list2, new Comparator() {
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        return list1.indexOf(o1) - list1.indexOf(o2);
     }});
```

Update: Since `indexOf` could take some time if the list is unsorted, and since this method would be called *very* often, it may be better to first store the indices of the objects in a Map, i.e. create a HashMap {item: list1.indexOf(item)} and use this map in the `compare` method.

Putting it together, and using the names from your example:

```
final Map<Field, Integer> indices = new HashMap<Field, Integer>();
for (int i=0; i < oldValues.size(); i++) {
    indices.put(oldValues.get(i), i);
}
Collections.sort(auditMap, new Comparator<Field>() {
    public int compare(Field o1, Field o2) {
        int index1 = indices.containsKey(o1) ? indices.get(o1) : -1;
        int index2 = indices.containsKey(o2) ? indices.get(o2) : -1;
        return index1 - index2;
     }});
```

Comment: Can i order the data before putting into oldValues list ?

Comment: i have query regarding below sort function,if the auditMap and olsdValues has unequal data then how the sorting will work.

Comment: @pars In case o1 is not in oldValues, index1 is -1 (same for o2). Sorting should still work, putting those elements at the front of auditMap. To put them at the end, change the -1 in the code to oldValues.size()+1.

Comment: but this code works differently ,this code does the sorting also copies the data not present in one list to other

Comment: Idont want the data from auditMap to be copied to oldValues,i just need sort,even if the size is not equal

Comment: @pars Excuse me? The values in `oldValues` are added to the `indices` map, but not to the `auditMap` list, and neither are values from `auditMap` added to `oldValues`. Can you please point out the place where you think the values are copied?